# variant pixel buffer to vector using boost::apply_visitor

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, apply-visitor

I am trying to convert variablepixelbuffer.vbuffer() to a vector of double values using apply_visitor in boost.

I came with this piece of code till now :

```
struct GetVector : public boost::static_visitor<std::vector<double>>
{
    //values will be returned in a pair.  double is
    // used since it can contain the value for any pixel type
    typedef std::vector<double> result_type;
    template<typename T
    void myfunction (const T& i) {  // function:
        result_type.push_back(static_cast<double>(*i));
    }

    template<typename T>
    result_type
    operator() (const T& v)
    {
        typedef typename T::element_type::value_type value_type;
        std::for_each (v->data(), v->data() + v->num_elements(), myfunction);
        return result_type;
    }
};
/* pixel-example-start */
void
readPixelData(const FormatReader& reader,
    std::ostream&       stream,int x,int y,int w,int h)
{
    // Change the current series to this index
    reader.setSeries(0);
    // Get total number of planes (for this image index)
    dimension_size_type pc = reader.getImageCount();
    // Pixel buffer
    VariantPixelBuffer buf;
    dimension_size_type xd = x;
    dimension_size_type yd = y;
    dimension_size_type wd = w;
    dimension_size_type hd = h;
    // Loop over planes (for this image index)
    for (dimension_size_type p = 0 ; p < pc; p++)
    {
        // Read the entire plane into the pixel buffer.
        reader.openBytes(p, buf,xd,yd,wd,hd);
    }
    GetVector visitor;
    GetVector::result_type result = boost::apply_visitor(visitor, buf.vbuffer());
}
```

But i am getting some long errors, and some piece of it are

> /usr/include/boost/variant/detail/apply_visitor_unary.hpp:60:43:
>   required from ‘typename Visitor::result_type
>   boost::apply_visitor(Visitor&, Visitable&) [with Visitor =
>   MinMaxVisitor; Visitable =
>   boost::variant >,
>   boost::mpl::v_item >,
>   boost::mpl::v_item
>
> > , boost::mpl::v_item >,
> >     boost::mpl::v_item >,
> >     boost::mpl::v_item >,
> >     boost::mpl::v_item
> >     , boost::mpl::v_item
> >     , boost::mpl::v_item
> >     , boost::mpl::v_item
> >
> > > , boost::mpl::v_item
> > >       , boost::mpl::vector0, 1>, 1>, 1>, 1>, 1>, 1>, 1>, 1>, 1>, 1>, 1> >, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_,
> > >       boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>;
> > >       typename Visitor::result_type = std::vector >]’ read_subimage.C:82:85:   required from here
> > >       /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4417:14: error: must use ‘.*’ or
> > >       ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘__f (...)’, e.g. ‘(...
> > >       ->* __f) (...)’

How can i reslove this, I need to get the pixel buffer data into vector .

Comment: Besides the apparent syntax error here: `template<typename T`, `myfunction` is a member template - you'll probably have to do something like `std::mem_fn(&GetVector::myfunction<T>)` to be able to pass it to STL algorithms, unless you use a lambda instead.

Comment: Also, `GetVector` doesn't hold any state that `myfunction` needs, so it could be a static member template instead. Then you'd "just" need to pass `&GetVector::myfunction<T>`.

Comment: Hey @melak47 thanks for the tip , i will try this

Comment: @melak47 i made the function as static and called it like .. std::for_each (v->data(), v->data() + v->num_elements(), &GetVector::myfunction); Now its shows me an error that template argument deduction/substitution failed:
read_subimage.C:56:86: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Funct’
       std::for_each (v->data(), v->data() + v->num_elements(), &GetVector::myfunction);
                                                                                      ^

Comment: You can't get a function pointer to a function template, only to a particular instantiation of it. To do that, you need to provide the template arguments (`T` in this case).